# To change the page content and title of zencart

Tags: zen-cart

I have installed a footer menu model. Now i have a default page "Page 2". I want to change the page and the title also. How can i change the page content.

I have tried like below.

Go to admin - Tools - Ez-pages - Page 2

But there are no page named Page 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put together a series of tutorials on how to modify these define pages in Zen Cart:

http://www.kerrinhardy.com/2010/01/12/more-information-zen-cart-sidebox/

The relevant tutorials are:

- Update Page Heading of Page 2, Page 3 or Page 4 in More Information
  sidebox
- Edit contents of Page 2, Page 3 or Page 4 in More Information sidebox
- Edit name of link to Page 2, Page 3 or Page 4 in More Information
  sidebox
- Update Page Title of Page 2, Page 3 or Page 4 in More Information
  sidebox

However, if the footer addon isn't using the Zen Cart functionality and actually has the 'Page 2' link hard coded, you will need to modify this in the footer add-on template file.

Hope this helps.